# Multiple instances of an application

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose

I have an application for which I need to spawn 2 instances in the same host defining 2 different environments.

The application **docker-compose.yml**

```yml
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    image: nginx
    depends_on:
      - db

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my_reverse_proxy_network
```

As you can see I'm using a network so my reverse proxy can communicate with them.

Now lets run the instances:

```
$ docker-compose -p proj1 up -d
Creating proj1_db_1
Creating proj1_web_1

$ docker-compose -p proj2 -f docker-compose.yml -f proj2-overrides.yml up -d
Creating proj2_db_1
Creating proj2_web_1
```

**proj2-overrides.yml** contains some specific env variables to configure the proj2 environment.

```yml
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    environment:
      HOST: proj2.myapp.net
```

And here is my problem:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID ... NAMES
23a13acd4ffc ... proj2_web_1
dbeea953f805 ... proj2_db_1
df376b9ee400 ... proj1_web_1
bf246e503fc6 ... proj1_db_1
a06064cb0660 ... my_reverse_proxy

$ docker inspect -f '...{{.IPAddress}}...' bf246e503fc6
172.21.0.3

$ docker exec -ti proj1_web_1 ping db
PING db (172.21.0.5): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.21.0.5: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
```

My `proj1_web_1` is linked to `proj2_db_1`.

I imagine that it is because Docker takes the first available db container or something like that.

**How can I prevent one project to link to the other one's containers ?**

(... but still being able to communicate with my reverse proxy)

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to have 2 compose files and not put your whole setup in one file?

Comment: Are you talking about `proj2-overrides.yml` ? This file is an extension of `docker-compose.yml`, that's why I'm loading both for proj2. It only contains the specific settings for proj2, ie: environment variables.

Comment: No, what I meant is why you need both docker-compose.yml and proj2-overrides.yml  and not just one combined compose file as anyway both instances are running on the same docker host. The env variables can anyway be defined by service so currently I don't see the need there. I mean you can put proj2_web_1, proj1_web_1 container in the same compose as well. In general I just think that I didn't got the question correctly.

Comment: I've just added a `proj2-overrides.yml` sample in the question so you can see what it is used for. I'm simply [extending](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#different-environments) my `docker-compose.yml` here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your DB is on the same reverse proxy network with everything else. Create a separate network for just the proxy that the web servers talk to, and let docker-compose create the default networks for all other containers to talk internally among themselves:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    image: nginx
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - default
      - proxy

networks:
  proxy:
    external:
      name: my_reverse_proxy_network
```

Comment: I tried that and it does not allow my reverse proxy to communicate with my web service. I don't understand why.

Comment: An inspect of your web service and reverse proxy network may help debug this.

Comment: It was working, I only had a missing setting in my reverse proxy (in this case [Traefik](https://traefik.io/))

Comment: Good to hear, that reminds me of issues I had with nginx-proxy including container IP's that it couldn't reach in its dynamic config. Thanks for following up.